# Java Graphics - Shapes wont fill

Tags: java, swing, colors, paintcomponent, shapes

Im trying to learn some Java here and im stuck with a problem. Program is supposed to generate random filed shapes but its only generating random empty shapes.

Last parameter is wether or not its filled but seems to have no effect.

Heres the code.

```
  public DrawPanel()
    {
        setBackground( Color.WHITE );

        lines = new MyLine[1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((5 - 1) + 1))];
        rectangles = new MyRectangle[1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((5 - 1) + 1))];
        ovals = new MyOval[1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((5 - 1) + 1))];

        // create lines
        for ( int count = 0; count < lines.length; count++ )
        {
            // generate random coordinates
            int x1 = randomNumbers.nextInt( 300 );
            int y1 = randomNumbers.nextInt( 300 );
            int x2 = randomNumbers.nextInt( 300 );
            int y2 = randomNumbers.nextInt( 300 );

            // generate a random color
            Color color = new Color( randomNumbers.nextInt( 256 ), 
                    randomNumbers.nextInt( 256 ), randomNumbers.nextInt( 256 ) );

            // add the line to the list of lines to be displayed
            lines[count] = new MyLine( x1, y1, x2, y2, color );


            // create Rectangles
            for ( int countR = 0; countR < rectangles.length; countR++ )
            {
                // generate random coordinates
                int x1R = randomNumbers.nextInt( 300 );
                int y1R = randomNumbers.nextInt( 300 );
                int x2R = randomNumbers.nextInt( 300 );
                int y2R = randomNumbers.nextInt( 300 );

                // generate a random color
                Color colorR = new Color( randomNumbers.nextInt( 256 ), 
                        randomNumbers.nextInt( 256 ), randomNumbers.nextInt( 256 ) );

                // add the rectangles to the list of rectangles to be displayed
                rectangles[countR] = new MyRectangle( x1R, y1R, x2R, y2R, colorR, true );


                // create Ovals
                for ( int countO = 0; countO < ovals.length; countO++ )
                {
                    // generate random coordinates
                    int x1O = randomNumbers.nextInt( 300 );
                    int y1O = randomNumbers.nextInt( 300 );
                    int x2O = randomNumbers.nextInt( 300 );
                    int y2O = randomNumbers.nextInt( 300 );

                    // generate a random color
                    Color colorO = new Color( randomNumbers.nextInt( 256 ), 
                            randomNumbers.nextInt( 256 ), randomNumbers.nextInt( 256 ) );

                    // add the rectangles to the list of rectangles to be displayed
                    ovals[countO] = new MyOval( x1O, y1O, x2O, y2O, colorO, true );


                } // end Ovals for  


            } // end Rectangle for   

        } // end for
    } // end DrawPanel constructor



   // for each shape array, draw the individual shapes
   public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
   {
      super.paintComponent( g );



//      // draw the lines
//      for ( MyLine line : lines )
//         line.draw( g );

      for ( MyRectangle rectangle : rectangles )
          {rectangle.draw(g);}

      for( MyOval oval : ovals)
          {  oval.draw(g);   }

      for( MyLine line : lines)
      {  line.draw(g);   }




   }



public class MyRectangle {

    private int x1 = 0; // x-coordinate of first endpoint
    private int y1 = 0; // y-coordinate of first endpoint
    private int x2 = 0; // x-coordinate of second endpoint
    private int y2 = 0; // y-coordinate of second endpoint
    private Color myColor; // color of this shape
    boolean filled ; // Boolean flag if shape is filled

    public MyRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color myColor,
            boolean filled) {

        super();
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
        this.myColor = myColor;
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    public MyRectangle() {

        super();
        setUpperLeftX(0,0);
        setUpperLeftY(0,0);
        this.myColor = Color.BLACK;
        this.filled = false;
    }


    public int getUpperLeftX(int x1, int x2){

        // The upper-left x-coordinate is the smaller of the two x-coordinate values

        if(x1 <= x2){

            return x1;

        }
        else{

            return x2;
        }



    }

    public void setUpperLeftX(int x1, int x2){

        if(x1 >= 0){
        this.x1 = x1;
        }
        else{this.x1 = 0;}
        if(x2 >= 0){
        this.x2 = x2;   
        }
        else{this.x2 = 0;}



    }

    public int getUpperLeftY(int x1, int x2){

    // the upperleft y-coordinate is the smaller of the two y-coordinate values

        if(y1 <= y2){

            return y1;

        }
        else{

            return y2;
        }

    }  

    public void setUpperLeftY(int x1, int x2){

        if(y1 >= 0){
        this.y1 = x1;
        }
        else{this.y1 = 0;}
        if(y2 >= 0){
        this.y2 = x2;   
        }
        else{this.y2 = 0;}

    } 

    public int getWidth(int x1, int x2){

        int width = 0;


        // the width is the absolute value of the difference between the two x-coordinate values

        width = (x1 - x2);

        return Math.abs(width);

    }

    public int getHeight(){

        int height = 0;

        // the height is the absolute value of the difference between the two y-coordinate values.


        height = (y1 - y2);

        return Math.abs(height);

    }

    public void draw( Graphics g )
       {




          g.setColor( getMyColor() );
          g.drawRect(getX1(), getY1(), getX2(), getY2());
       } // end method draw

    public int getX1() {
        return x1;
    }

    public void setX1(int x1) {
        this.x1 = x1;
    }

    public int getY1() {
        return y1;
    }

    public void setY1(int y1) {
        this.y1 = y1;
    }

    public int getX2() {
        return x2;
    }

    public void setX2(int x2) {
        this.x2 = x2;
    }

    public int getY2() {
        return y2;
    }

    public void setY2(int y2) {
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    public Color getMyColor() {
        return myColor;
    }

    public void setMyColor(Color myColor) {
        this.myColor = myColor;
    }

    public boolean isFilled() {
        return filled;
    }

    public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
        this.filled = filled;
    }



public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();      
      JFrame application = new JFrame();

      application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      application.add( panel );
      application.setSize( 600, 600 );
      application.setVisible( true );
   } // end main
```

Comment: Check out [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for information about the Shape class of Java which might simplify your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never run fill method

Try replacing your draw method with this:

```
public void draw( Graphics g )
   {          
      g.setColor( getMyColor() );
      if(filled)
         g.fillRect(getX1(), getY1(), getWidth(), getHeight());
      else
         g.drawRect(getX1(), getY1(), getWidth(), getHeight());
   } // end method draw
```

you also seem to use second coordinates instead of width and height